# Xen domu apache

Tags: apache2, network-bridge, xen

This is a *Xen bridge* issue. I have a web server guest. When people click on a web page, the apache logs show the IP of the bridge, not the persons IP who clicked on the page. The bridge should be transparent (and is on my older Debian configuration)

I have a pretty straight-forward set up, or at least I think I do. Any ideas why my guest web server logs are not seeing the users IP? What would be the typical cause?

```
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# The loopback network interface
auto lo xenbr0 xenbr1
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
iface xenbr0 inet static
bridge_ports p6p1
address 74.xxx.xxx.5
netmask 255.255.255.240
gateway 74.xxx.xxx.14
bridge_stp off
dns-nameservers 68.xxx.xxx.146 68.xxx.xxx.98
iface xenbr1 inet static
bridge_ports eth1
bridge_stp off
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
post-up ethtool --offload p6p1 gso off tso off sg off gro off
post-up ethtool --offload eth1 gso off tso off sg off gro off
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
#iface p6p1 inet6 auto


bridge name bridge id   STP enabled interfaces
xenbr0  8000.00a0244d1fbe   no  p6p1
vif2.0
vif7.0
vif8.0
xenbr1  8000.feffffffffff   no  vif1.0
vif2.1
vif7.1
vif8.1
vif9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding these to the `sysctl`

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0

net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter = 0

net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_filter = 0

net.ipv4.conf.xenbr0.arp_filter = 0
```